# How to handle relationship in rails 3.1 between a table and 2 other mutually exclusive tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

There is an invoice in our rails 3.1.4 app. An invoice could be generated either from one quote OR one or many lease booking items, but not from both of them at the same time. So one invoice either has one quote or has many lease usage items. Now we are thinking to create a intermediate table with invoice id and an artificial field invoice_item_id (could be either a quote id or lease usage item id) to store the quote or lease usage items for the invoice. However we are not sure about the relationship between invoice and quote and between invoice and lease usage items. We can not say invoice has_one quote because some invoices will have none of the quote. On the other hand we can't not say invoice has_many lease usage items because some may have none. What's the better way to handle this type of relationship in rails 3.1.4? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Polymorphic Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations): "With polymorphic associations, a model can belong to more than one other model, on a single association", so in your case `invoce_item_id` belongs to an invoiceable (a quote or a lease usage item).

Answer (score 1):

IMO you should be fine using has_one/has_many relationships as you describe above.  It is valid to use these relationships even if the reference is not populated.

You could handle the mutually-exclusive part via an ActiveRecord validation:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#validations-overview

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :quote 
  has_many :lease_usage_items

  validates :cannot_have_quote_and_lease_usage_items
```